# Creating a dynamic grid with Javascript

Tags: javascript, dynamic

I'm very new to JS so pardon anything that may be totally, utterly wrong.

I'm trying to create a 16x16 grid of divs dynamically. My logic is that I'd create a container for all of the grid, inside the container I'd append 16 rows and in each row I'd append 16 boxes. I have a rough idea of my code and I wanted to check if it is valid logic and JS.

```
/* Creating the grid */
function grid() {
    var container = document.createElement("div");
    container.id = "main";
    container.className = "container";

    for (i=0, i<16, i+=1) {
        var row = document.getElementbyId('main').appendChild('div');
        row.className = "row";
        row.id = "row" + i;
    };

    for (j=0, j<16, j+=1) {
        for (k=0, k<16, k+=1) {
            var box = document.getElementbyId("row" + j).appendChild('div');
            box.className = "box";
        };
    };
};
```

Comment: It is not. `.appendChild` accepts nodes, not strings. You should change `appendChild('div')` to `appendChild(document.createElement("div"))`

Comment: oh yes I forgot about that. You have to create the element before appending it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **CAUSE**

There are some issues with the code.

- Syntax for `for` loop is `for(init;condition;final-expression)`, see manual for [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for).
- `appendChild` requires nodes not strings.
- Function `grid()` doesn't do anything. It should either return a node, accept a node to append to or insert content somewhere, it's up for you to decide.

> **DEMO**

See the demo below for corrected code and demonstration.

```js
/* Creating the grid */
function grid(el) {
    var container = document.createElement("div");
    container.id = "main";
    container.className = "container";

    for (i=0; i<16; i+=1) {
        var row = document.createElement("div");
        row.className = "row";
        row.id = "row" + i;
      
        for (k=0; k<16; k+=1) {
            var box = document.createElement("div"); 
            box.className = "box";
            row.appendChild(box);
        };
      
        container.appendChild(row);      
    };
  
    el.appendChild(container);
};

grid(document.body);
```

```css
.row {
  border:1px solid green;  
  height:1em;
  line-height:1em;
}

.box {
  display:inline-block;
  width:6.25%;
  height:1em;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  border:1px solid red; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yep the logic is correct although theres a number of syntax/type errors and it would be more efficient too store reusable variables and to have only 2 loops as below

```
function grid(d) {
 var container = d.createElement("div");
 container.id = "main";
 container.className = "container";

  for (i=0; i<16; i++) {
    var row = container.appendChild(d.createElement('div'));
    row.className = "row";
    row.id = "row" + i;

     for (k=0; k<16; k++) {
        var box = row.appendChild(d.createElement('div'));
        box.className = "box";
     };
  };

  d.body.appendChild(container);

};

grid(document);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
/* Creating the grid */
function grid (content) {
    var container = content.appendChild(document.createElement("div"));
    container.id = "main";
    container.className = "container";

    for (var i = 0;i < 16;++i) {
        var row = container.appendChild(document.createElement("div"));
        row.className = "row";
        row.id = "row" + i;
        for (var k = 0;k < 16;++k) {
            var box = row.appendChild(document.createElement("div"));
            box.className = "box";
        }
    }
}

grid(document.body)
```

Some errors in your code:

- `container` needs to be inserted somewhere too.
- `appendChild` accepts nodes, not strings
- `for loop` uses `;` to separate expressions, not `,` (they all are optional)

Answer (score 0):

You should pay attention to your misuse of syntax in for loop.

You may want this:

```
'use strict';

function grid() {
    var container = document.createElement('div');
    container.id = "main";
    container.className = "container";

    for (var i = 0; i < 16; i++) {

        var row = document.createElement('div');
        row.className = "row";
        row.id = "row" + i;

        for (var j = 0; j < 16; j++) {
            var box = document.createElement('div');
            box.className = 'box';
            row.appendChild(box);
        }

        container.appendChild(row);
    }

    return container;
}

console.log(grid());

// and you should use 
// document.getElementById('xxx').appendChild(grid());
```

You may refer to:

- [Document.getElementById()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)
- [Node.appendChild()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild)
- [Document.createElement()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement)
- [Nicholas C. Zakas - Speed up your JavaScript, Part 4](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/02/03/speed-up-your-javascript-part-4/), which tells that you might append all the child nodes to the parent node, and then append the parent node to *its* parent node.

Answer (score 0):

You have so many syntax errors that you need to be aware of, like :

The for loop, it should contain semi colons not commas...

And you need to create the div everytime before appending it, like you did for the container.

Here's a working code :

```
function grid(){
    var container = document.createElement("div");
    container.id = "main";
    container.className = "container";
    document.body.appendChild(container);
    var main = document.getElementById('main');
    for (var i=0; i<16; i++) {
        var row = document.createElement("div");
        row.className = "row";
        row.id = "row" + i;
        main.appendChild(row);
        var roww = document.getElementById('row'+i);
        for (var j=0; j<16; j++) {
            var box = document.createElement("div");
            box.className = "box";
            roww.appendChild(box);
        }
    }
}
window.onload = grid();
```

Here's A [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ayadi102/198ospjm/1/)